# Вычислить время до часа X в милисекундах

Tags: время, php

Нужно вычислить на стороне сервера оставшееся время до часа X в миллисекундах.
Вчера ломал голову весь день но так и не понял как это сделать.

Comment: @DaniilP, на практике воспользоваться этим (интервал времени с миллисекундной точность) все равно не удастся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приглядитесь к ф-ям time(), microtime(), mktime() и date()

```
list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
$hour_X = mktime(18,0,0,3,11,2014);  // Час Х
echo ((float)$hour_X - (float)$sec - (float)$msec)*1000;
```

Update: поправил, сразу по невнимательности вывел в микросекундах

Comment: Протестил у себя, выдает не коректный результат, так как ф-я неправильно определила летнее время (я из Беларуси, у нас круглый год летнее) как зимнее. Самый простой способ исправить, хотя и устаревший, добавить к mktime() еще один параметр равный 1:

    mktime(18,0,0,3,11,2014,1)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @MDJHD, спасибо, все работает. Отметил ответ как правильный.